# How to run test on the source tree in bazel?

Tags: bazel

I am migrating a project from cmake to bazel. I have a folder contains some python code and some `genrules`.
I had a test script run all the python tests in this folder recursively.
So basically I need all py files under this folder as `data` for the test script. But given there are some genrule I need to run, there are some BUILD files, so that `glob(["**/*.py"])` can't get through.

For example, we have a folder `python` contains following files.

- `python/BUILD`
- `python/test_a.py`
- `python/folder_a/BUILD` this one has genrule in it.
- `python/folder_a/folder_b/BUILD` this one has genrule as well.
- `python/folder_a/folder_b/folder_c/test_b.py`

I want to run the test script under `python/`, it will run all the `test_*.py` recursively. Now we want to wrap it as a `sh_test` in bazel. So we need to specify all the `test_*.py` in the `data` field. But there is no easy way to do that since `glob()` can't get through `python/folder_a/BUILD` and `python/folder_a/folder_b/BUILD`.

It will be quite convenience if I can run this script in the source tree. But it seems that bazel didn't provide this. Adding `local = 1` in `sh_test` only make the runfiles tree writable.

I know it is not a good way to use bazel to test, but sometimes it is too much work for migrating everything at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of an easy way to obtain all of the target names *in* a BUILD file, but there is a Bazel query you can run to get the target names, which you can then collect in a `filegroup` target to reference in the `sh_test.data` attribute.

```
bazel query 'filter(".*:test_.*\.py", kind("source file", //python/...:*) + kind("generated file", //python/...:*))'
```

Breaking this down:

1. `kind("source file", //python/...:*)` queries all **source** file
   targets in the `//python` package recursively. This collects the
   normal source files.
2. `kind("generated file", //python/...:*)` queries all **generated**
   file targets in the `//python` package recursively. This collects
   the genrule'd files.
3. `filter(".*:test_.*\.py", ...)` filters the results that contain
   only targets in the form of `//any/package:test_name.py`

For example, running

```
bazel query 'filter(".*:test_.*\.py", kind("source file", //src/...:* + //tools/...:*) + kind("generated file", //src/...:* + //tools/...:*))'
```

on Bazel's own source tree finds one target: `//src/test/py/bazel:test_base.py`

Comment: Although maybe not a perfect choice, but it works. In this case I have to add all python files into bazel, which is also a couple of works.